# Deleting Data instead of using Migration

Tags: ios, database, swift3, realm, xcode8

#### Deleting Data instead of using Migration

In my code I added a property to my realm class. Is there a way to delete the data and get rid off my whole database instead of using migration?

I'm still testing that's why I probably won't need Migration for now.

Please help me, I'm really struggling with using Migration

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are only testing locally you can delete the app and re-install. If you already have your app on the App Store and want to prepare migrations for users you can have a look at the [Migrations Sample App](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/ios/swift-3.0/Migration) from Realm.

Try this on your AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

// Old data models
/* V0
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var firstName = ""
    dynamic var lastName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
*/

// V1
class Person: Object {
    dynamic var fullName = ""        // combine firstName and lastName into single field
    dynamic var age = 0
}


class Person: Object {
    dynamic var fullName = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}

func bundleURL(_ name: String) -> URL? {
    return Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "realm")
}

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        // copy over old data files for migration
        let defaultURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL!
        let defaultParentURL = defaultURL.deletingLastPathComponent()

        if let v0URL = bundleURL("default-v0") {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultURL)
                try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: v0URL, to: defaultURL)
            } catch {}
        }

        // define a migration block
        // you can define this inline, but we will reuse this to migrate realm files from multiple versions
        // to the most current version of our data model
        let migrationBlock: MigrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in
            if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: Person.className()) { oldObject, newObject in
                    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
                        // combine name fields into a single field
                        let firstName = oldObject!["firstName"] as! String
                        let lastName = oldObject!["lastName"] as! String
                        newObject?["fullName"] = "\(firstName) \(lastName)"
                    }
                }
            }
            print("Migration complete.")
        }

        Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 2, migrationBlock: migrationBlock)

        // print out all migrated objects in the default realm
        // migration is performed implicitly on Realm access
        print("Migrated objects in the default Realm: \(try! Realm().objects(Person.self))")

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helped me

Answer (score 1):

See [Realm.Configuration.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.7.0/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:vVC10RealmSwift5Realm13Configuration28deleteRealmIfMigrationNeededSb).